# Select item in details form dropdown when datagrid item is selected

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, datagrid, master-detail

I have this datagrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgCompetenteN" includeIn="Test" left="10" right="472" top="69" bottom="149"
             dataProvider="{colCompetente}" editable="false">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ID Competență" dataField="idCompetenta"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Denumire Competență" dataField="denCompetenta"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Competență Superioară" dataField="idCompSuperioara" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="idCompSuperioara" itemRenderer="renderers.CompetentaSuperioara"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

and this form:

```
<s:Form includeIn="Test" x="536" y="69">
    <s:FormItem label="Denumire competenta">
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="Help String"></s:Label>
        </s:helpContent>
        <s:TextInput text="{dgCompetenteN.selectedItem.denCompetenta}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Competenta superioara">
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="Help String"></s:Label>
        </s:helpContent>
        <s:DropDownList dataProvider="{colCompetente}" 
                        labelField="denCompetenta">
        </s:DropDownList>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

What I want to do is, when I select an item in the datagrid, the selected item of the dropdown should be the correct one (the one which has the field idCompSuperioara equal to the third element in the selected datagrid row).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

**The itemClickHandler:**

```
protected function dgCompetenteN_itemClickHandler(event:ListEvent):void
{
  for each (var o:Object in colCompetente)
  {
    if (o.idCompSuperioara == dgCompetenteN.selectedItem.idCompSuperioara)
    {
      ddlCompetenta.selectedItem = o;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**The DataGrid:**

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgCompetenteN" includeIn="Test" left="10" right="472" top="69" bottom="149" dataProvider="{colCompetente}" editable="false" itemClick="dgCompetenteN_itemClickHandler(event)">
  <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ID Competență" dataField="idCompetenta"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Denumire Competență" dataField="denCompetenta"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Competență Superioară" dataField="idCompSuperioara" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="idCompSuperioara" itemRenderer="renderers.CompetentaSuperioara"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

**The form:**

```
<s:Form includeIn="Test" x="536" y="69">
    <s:FormItem label="Denumire competenta">
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="Help String"></s:Label>
        </s:helpContent>
        <s:TextInput text="{dgCompetenteN.selectedItem.denCompetenta}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Competenta superioara">
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="Help String"></s:Label>
        </s:helpContent>
        <s:DropDownList id="ddlCompetenta" dataProvider="{colCompetente}" 
                        labelField="denCompetenta">
        </s:DropDownList>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason!
Works perfect with this condition: 
if (parseInt(o.idCompetenta) == parseInt(dgCompetente.selectedItem.idCompSuperioara))